# Round a number up in ruby

Tags: ruby, rounding

Just wondering how would i round the number "15.755" up to "15.76" in ruby.

I have tried the round method, but doesnt produce the result im looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this not what you want?

```
>> 15.755.round(2)
=> 15.76
```

Ah, you are probably using 1.8 (why btw?). There you can do the following:

```
>> (15.755 * 100).round / 100.0
=> 15.76
```

You could wrap that up in a helper function:

```
def round(n, precision)
  raise "Precision needs to be >= 0" if precision < 0
  power_of_ten = 10 ** precision
  (n * power_of_ten).round / power_of_ten.to_f
end

round(15.755, 2) #=> 15.76
```

Comment: Agreed. But perhaps, since he is talking about "rounding up", a `ceil`call should be more appropriate in your helper function.

Comment: I wasn't sure if OP really always wants to round up, but if he does it's easy enough for him to change. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: 15.755.round(2) worked like a charm, i didnt know you can pass 2 to the function. On a side note, is raise how you raise exceptions in ruby? Im just learning.

Comment: @namtax Yes: http://web.njit.edu/all_topics/Prog_Lang_Docs/html/ruby/syntax.html#raise

Comment: @MichaelKohl cool, good to know, so simple compared to other languages.