# How to round up a number in an angularjs template file

Tags: angularjs

In an angularjs html template file, I need to round a number (i.e. 5.12 to 6).

```
<td>{{number| currency:$:0}}</td>
```

I tried doing:

```
number.ceil
```

and also tried the solutions from the following articles:

[Ruby Always Round Up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542681/ruby-always-round-up)

[Round a number up in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837815/round-a-number-up-in-ruby)

but none of them seems to work (the entire td column would be blank with no numbers).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `offer.amount` return? What do you mean _"won't work"_? What is your question?

Comment: This is django, not ruby/erb.

Comment: I couldn't console.log(offer.amount) @JagdeepSingh . could you please give me some pointers?

Comment: why is it a django file? even though the file extension ends with html.erb? @rewritten

Comment: There is no such thing as "double curly braces" and "pipe filters" in ERB. ERB uses `<%= function(args) %>` to include computed content into the rendered text (which can be html). That piece of template in your question is in fact the way it's done in django/jinja2 templating language (with double curlies and filters)

Comment: In other words, you seem to believe that you have ruby code there, but it can't be ruby. It would be interesting to know the reason of your belief, by sharing some more detail about the project you are working on (framework etc)

Comment: I inherited this project and the entire backend is ran by ruby with ruby gem and all files extension ends with` .html.erb`. No one seems to have bought up python/django so far. But again, I could be wrong.

Comment: either way - what would you recommend to get this working? I tried for hours and couldn't solve this seemingly simple problem to round up a number. Thanks. @rewritten

Comment: Using `<%=  %>` or `<% %>` instead of `{{ }}` would be a good start

Comment: ah okay. you guys get me thinking - it is an angularJS template file.

Comment: Indeed angular uses the same syntax as Django templates

Answer (score 1):

create a filter in the controller

```
 .filter('roundup', function () {
        return function (value) {
            return Math.ceil(value);
        };
    })
```

then `<td>{{number| roundup}}</td>`

Answer (score 0):

Use Math.round(number) (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

```
{{ Math.round(number) | currency:$:0 }}
```

Comment: this doesn't work in angularjs - you would have to inject it to the directives